# Expiry or expiration?

Tags: word-choice, differences

Do these 2 sentences have particular reasons? Could we use both?

A. Not less than 30 days of the expiration.

B. Not less than 30 days of the expiry date.

Comment: expiry is not an adjective. it is a noun.

Answer (score 12):

[Expiry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Expiry) and [expiration](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expiration)
are synonyms that can be used interchangeably: (from TFD)

> - a coming to an end of a contract period; "the expiry of his driver's license", the expiration of a contract;   termination.

[Ngram - BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expiry%20date%2C%20expiration%20date&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexpiry%20date%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexpiration%20date%3B%2Cc0): [expiry date](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/expiry-date) vs expiration date

[NGram - AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expiry%20date%2Cexpiration%20date&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexpiry%20date%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexpiration%20date%3B%2Cc0): expiry date vs expiration date

Ngram shows that 'expiration' is the term more used in AmE while in BrE both terms are used, though 'expiry' appears to be more prevalent.

> - (UK)  Check the expiry date on your passport.
> - ( US) Check the expiration date on your passport.

- not less than 30 days before expiry/expiration (date).

Comment: Yeah, if you say "expiry" in the US you will probably be understood, but you're apt to get a queer look.

Answer (score 2):

> A. Not less than 30 days of the expiration.
>
> B. Not less than 30 days of the expiry date.

Those two fragments are ungrammatical.  When using "*of* the expiration" we cannot use "not less than".

*Not less than 30 days of the expiration  [UNGRAMMATICAL]

At least 30 days from expiration|expiry  OK

No more than 30 days from expiration|expiry OK

Within 30 days of expiration|expiry OK

Answer (score -1):

We could talk about the date of expiration, as'expiration' is the noun version of the word. The word 'investigation' is a noun, also: 'the cost of the investigation was very high' 'There was a complication', etc. when you look at 'expiry date', 'date' is the noun, and 'expiry' is the adjective that relates to the noun; start date, renewal date, etc. I would say, however, that it would be necessary to say 'The expiration DATE OF THE (product,etc.), as there has to be the expiration OF something. Also, the use of 'of' is not the best here; l would say '30 days BEFORE/ FROM/AFTER the expiry date/date of expiration'. The thing is to use a preposition that works with a point in time/date. Hope this helps.